# Discord.js Add roles in event "messageReactionAdd"

Tags: discord.js

I can't add roles in 'messageReactionAdd' (error on add). Please is for a private discord bot. Thanks

My code:

```js
bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    const member = reaction.message.guild.members.fetch(user.id)
    if (reaction.partial) {
        // If the message this reaction belongs to was removed, the fetching might result in an API error which should be handled
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the message: ', error);
            // Return as `reaction.message.author` may be undefined/null
            return;
        }
    }
    // Now the message has been cached and is fully available
    if(reaction.message.id === '853679407499313162'){
    const role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === '')
    console.log(reaction._emoji.name)
    if(reaction._emoji.name === ''){
        member.roles.add(role.id)
    } /*else if(reaction.name === ''){
        us
    }*/
//reaction.users.remove(user.id)
}
});
```

Console returns:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefine
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Log your `member` (console.log(member)) and check, if it is empty. You can also try checking if the `user` is **partial** or not and `.fetch()` him, after you checked it. [This](https://github.com/Toasty65/DiscordBot-Jarvis/blob/feature/perServerSettings/events/client/messageReactionAdd.js) is an example of how I structured this event

Answer (score 2):

your issue is `fetch` returns a promise, so resolve the promise and it should work

here is a guide on promises just in case you dont know how to resolve them

[discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html)

and additional one on mdn

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

[discord.js docs on fetch method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch)

Just a suggestion: you should use `await` instead of `then` as with ur current code it will be much cleaner